# "array of x is a 'variable' but is used like a method"

Tags: c#, arrays

Both instances of declarations don't work. I am a C# Novice, its obvious. I am attempting
to use a code from vb by converting to c#, I don't understand the problem so i can't fix it.

```
PictureBox[] pics = {picBackGround, picBackGroundTwo, picBarrier,picEnd,picFloor};

PictureBox[] pics = new PictureBox[] {picBackGround, picBackGroundTwo, picBarrier,picEnd,picFloor};

for (int i = 1; i < pics.Length; i++)
{            
    if (i > 3 && picUser.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pics(i).Bounds))
    {
        //Call CollisionDetectionRight()
    }   
}
```

Comment: Stop editing your question. Questions are questions, not responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must access an array with the square brackets `[]` for the index.

Example.

```
for (int i = 1; i < pics.Length; i++)
{            
            if (i > 3 && picUser.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pics[i].Bounds))
            {
                //Call CollisionDetectionRight()
            }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are accessing an element of an array wrongly:

```
pics(i).Bounds // tries to call the undefined function pics with the parameter i, and then get the Bounds member assigned to the returned element, which may not even be returned: it could be a void - will not work; throws
```

As the array has been declared with the [ ] operators, you must use them to access the elements:

```
pics[i].Bounds // gets the value of the member Bounds of the picture at the i location of pics - will work
```

Working code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < pics.Length; i++){            
        if (i > 3 && picUser.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pics[i].Bounds)){
            //Call CollisionDetectionRight()
        }   
}
```

**Note: You should probably initialize i as 0, as that is the base of an array, not 1**

Answer (score 2):

You should use `pics[i]` to access the array.  Square brackets are used to access array elements, where parentheses (`()`) are used for method calls.